# Parallel request in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to make parallel requests, fetch and combine the results.
To do so, I use this function :

```
    getStudent(query): Observable<any> {
    const code = this.http.get(
        `http://localhost:8090/etudiantFiltre?codEtudiant=${query}`
    );
    const prenom = this.http.get(
        `http://localhost:8090/etudiantFiltre?prenom1=${query}`
    );
    const nom = this.http.get(
        `http://localhost:8090/etudiantFiltre?patronyme=${query}`
    );
    return Observable.forkJoin([code, nom, prenom]).map(responses => {
        console.log(`code : ${code}
                     nom : ${nom}
                     prenom : ${prenom}`);
        return [].concat(...responses);
    });
}
```

When I use this alone, it works with a single word query like 'john'.

In order to support queries with spaces, I use this method that splits the query with spaces and call the method above with every single element. Then I use merge

```
getAllStudent(query) {
    const studentObservable: Observable<Response>[] = [];
    query.split(' ').forEach(element => {
        studentObservable.push(this.getStudent(element));
    });
    return Observable.merge(studentObservable);
}
```

And here's the call to the method

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllStudent('name firstname').subscribe(data => {
        this.st = data;
    });
}
```

But when I'm trying to print the result of the method, here's what I have and I don't really understand why:

```
{
    "_isScalar": false,
    "source": {
    "_isScalar": false,
    "sources": [
        {
        "_isScalar": false,
        "source": {
            "_isScalar": false,
            "source": {
            "_isScalar": false,
            "source": {
                "_isScalar": true,
                "value": {
                "url": "http://localhost:8090/etudiantFiltre?codEtudiant=firstname",
                "body": null,
                "reportProgress": false,
                "withCredentials": false,
                "responseType": "json",
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "normalizedNames": {},
                    "lazyUpdate": null,
                    "headers": {}
                    ...
```

Comment: hello, could you provide sample of json output for each kind of request. Actually i think your Observable try to recursively merge each Response Object together. In order to prevent this, please try to use  "Observable.merge([code, nom, prenom])", then for the "unification" part, i will provide you implementation when i will have asked json output

Comment: If you're asking about the result of the three request, they all have the same JSON body. As for the result, this is what I have when I use this.getAllStudent('name firstname') :
 
 "_isScalar": true,
     "value": {
     "url": "http://localhost:8090/etudiantFiltre?codEtudiant=firstname",
     "body": null,
     ...
 "_isScalar": true,
     "value": {
     "url": "http://localhost:8090/etudiantFiltre?patronyme=firstname",
     "body": null,
     ...
 "_isScalar": true,
     "value": {
     "url": "http://localhost:8090/etudiantFiltre?prenom1=firstname",
     "body": null,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can continue to use your forkJoin and use `combineLatest` to unify all requests together. if you want flat answer for your final observable. You can use `mergeMap` who will receive `Array<Response[]>` and can return simple `Response[]`

```
const keywords = ['yanis','git'];
const request$ = [];

keywords.forEach((keyword) => {
        //Create array of ForkJoin Observable.
        request$.push(forkJoin([
            this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?query='+keyword),
            this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?query='+keyword),
            this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?query='+keyword)
        ]));
});
// We combine all together and provide mergeMap strategy.
// Possible Observable here : combineLatest, forkJoin, combineAll ...
Observable.combineLatest(request$).mergeMap(e => {
    //All is merged to returned array. Here you can also deduplicate result.
    const returned = [];
    e.forEach(t => {
        t.forEach(i => returned.push(i));
    });
    return returned;

}).subscribe(e => {
    //You will receive each result returned by mergeMap.
    console.log(e);
});
```

Online sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-66ic6c?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Try `forkJoin` studentObservables too if you want parallel requests. Also, you can use `map` instead of `forEach` for cleaner code.

```
getAllStudent(query) {
    let studentObservables = query.split(' ')
        .map(element => this.getStudent(element)));
    return Observable.forkJoin(studentObservable);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllStudent('name firstname')
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```